# Musical Scores API for Android and IOS?

Tags: android, ios, api

I'm looking for an API that will generate a musical scores from MIDI file. I tried to search but I couldn't find one.

I'm trying to create an application for IOS and Android that will display a musical notes from piano/organ or midi file.

should you have any suggestions please let me know it is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### iOS:

Ugh, aren't we all.  There's no good objective-c midi libraries (generation or reading) that I've come across, and the music XML examples are all in c++.  However, there are TONS of c and c++ libraries dealing with MIDI.  For portability's sake, I recommend middl: http://code.google.com/p/middl/

### Android:

Though I've no experience with java, I hear the jFugue library brought up as an answer to every midi and java related question, so here it is: http://www.JFugue.org/

### Others:

There are two collections of c++ libraries for musical score typesetting, both operate as vector-graphics libraries, but Lilypad is MUCH larger and more complete than Belle-Bonne-Sage:

Lilypad: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.14/Documentation/web/index

Belle-Bonne-Sage: http://bellebonnesage.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Rendering musical scores is very hard business.  Once you have the notes extracted from MIDI, you will probably want to employ [Vexflow](http://www.vexflow.com/) for rendering in HTML5 via Canvas/SVG.  It doesn't handle all musical notation (triplets, for instance) but it does a pretty good job with simple output.  To get notes from a MIDI file there are a number of options.  My team makes a Python based music notation toolkit called [music21](http://web.mit.edu/music21/) which includes a parser for MIDI and output to Vexflow.  On iOS you'd need to duplicate the music21 MIDI to Vexflow conversion on your own.